# Kubernetes deployment

Tags: python-3.x, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I have deployed a pod in kubernetes cluster that run a python script.

The problem is i want to force the k8s to stop the container after the script complete his job and not to re-create another pod.

To be aware that i have tried to use kind:job but it doesn't fulfill my need.

I tried two types of kind, job and deployments.

With the deployment the pod always show status first completed after that crush with crashloopbackof error.

With the job the pod always show the status completed but i don't have the possibility to re-excute it with an automated way

Do you have any suggestions about that?

Comment: Why couldn't you use a `Job`? what you describe should be run as a `Job`.

Comment: Because i cannot restart the pod without doing some manual steps.

Comment: I want to use deployment and force the container to not restart until i modify something in git repo.

Comment: It sounds like you try to use containers as Virtual Machines? In a container you typically only run **one process** - if it is a service, you want that process to run forever - if it is a one-time-task, you want it to be executed and then terminated. I think you need to better describe what you try to do.

Comment: Exactly i want to run my python script on kube containers and after executing the script one time i want to terminate or stop it without creating another container or deleting the deployment.yml file

Comment: What do you mean with "terminate or stop it"? A script terminates when it has executed.

Comment: By terminate or stop it i mean that after the script finish his job the container stay at completed status or the container will be stoped or any other status except to be recreated every 5 minutes.

Comment: A kind `Job` does exactly this. Use `Job` and your problem is solved.

Comment: I tried to use the job today but it didn't helped me. Because i have to delete and recreate the job again but i want to use deployment.yaml file and when i push some code in git repo the helm operator will trigger a new deployment automatically. But with the job it's not possible in my case because the helm operator will not deploy another version of my app

Comment: If you deploy with `kubectl create -f job.yaml` and your job has a `generateName:` instead of `name:`, a new `Job` will be created each time.

Comment: Ah okay i see that so i have only to change the Name : by generateName : and when i push my code the k8s will generate new jobs okay thanks man i'll try it and see what i got

Answer (score 1):

I have posted community wiki answer to summarise the topic.

User [Jonas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/213269/jonas) has posted great suggestions:

> A kind `Job` does exactly this. Use `Job` and your problem is solved.

> If you deploy with `kubectl create -f job.yaml` and your job has a `generateName:` instead of `name:`, a new `Job` will be created each time.

For more information look at the documentation about [Jobs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/job/). See also information about [Gnerated values](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/using-api/api-concepts/#generated-values).